# What is the fastest way to write to s3 with a glue job? (Write to csv/parquet from dynamicframe)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

My current problem is that writing to s3 from a dynamic frame for small files is taking forever (more than an hour for a 100,000 line csv with ~100 columns. I am trying to write to parquet and csv, so I guess that's 2 write operations but it's still taking a long time. Is there something wrong with my code or is pyspark just usually this slow?

It should be noted that I am testing my script from a zeppelin notebook + dev endpoint (5 DPUs) to circumvent the 10 minute cold start, but I hope this isn't the reason why it's so slow. I am using spark 2.4 and python 3.

```
%pyspark
import boto3
import sys
import time
import uuid

from datetime import datetime
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name


def some_mapping(rec):
    # does something trivial


start = time.time()
print("Starting")
args = {
    "key": "2000.csv",
    "input_bucket": "my-input-bucket",
    "output_bucket": "my-output-bucket",

}
output_path = args["output_bucket"]
connection_options = {"path": output_path}
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
input_bucket = s3.Bucket(args["input_bucket"])
db = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name="us-east-1")

# Create a Glue context
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
DyF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://{}/{}".format(args["input_bucket"], args["key"])]},
    format="csv",
    format_options={
        "withHeader": True,
        "separator": ","
    }
)
mapped_DyF = DyF.map(some_mapping)

# Write to s3 
end = time.time()
print("Time: ",end-start) #Transformation takes less than 30 seconds
mapped_DyF.write(connection_type="s3",
                 connection_options={"path": "{}/parquet".format(args["output_bucket"])},
                 format="parquet")
end2 = time.time() # Takes forever
print("Time: ",end2-end)                 
mapped_DyF.write(connection_type="s3",
                 connection_options={"path": "{}/csv".format(args["output_bucket"]},
                 format="csv")
end3 = time.time()
print("Time: ",end3-start2) # Also takes forever

print("Time: ",end-start) # Total time is > 1 hour.
```

Comment: Have you considered analysing whether it's the writing, the reading or the mapping part? In other words, have you profiled this? I recommend adding a `.count` after your mapping to inspect the timings up to that point.

Comment: I believe my print statements suffice right? I printed time after each operation (mapping, and writing to s3) and the time it took to write was ~120 seconds per s3 (I used a 2000 line record this time). The mapping took ~9 seconds.

Comment: No, the intermediate timings which you try printing do not suffice, because Spark (and any library that uses it, like AWS Glue ETL) transformations **are lazy**, meaning they aren't executed unless you explicitly call an _action_ on a frame, like e.g. `.count()`. Try preceding your line of `end = time.time()` with `mapped_DyF.count()` and see how that impacts those ~9s.

Comment: So I added mapped_DyF.count() and it made everything slower. Is this normal/intended? It went from ~2-3 minutes to 10 minutes of total execution for 2000 lines in a csv.

Comment: Yes, this is intentional. You see, the `.count()` triggers the execution of your `some_mapping`. This way, you actually get an indication of how long your `some_mapping` takes. The increase from ~2-3 minutes total runtime to 10 minutes is overly large though (at most, it could've doubled). Without you showing the internals of your function`my_mapping` no-one can help you optimize the speed of your Spark job. Let me rephrase that too: the bulk of the execution time is likely not spent in the writing of your frame to S3, using Glue ETL, but in your `my_mapping`.